# Am I missing a package? Property 'findOne' does not exist on type 'Schema<Document<any, {}>, Model<any, any>, undefined>'

Tags: typescript, mongoose, webpack

I've been given the websites at my company to maintain and I've run into the error (Property 'findOne' does not exist on type 'Schema<Document<any, {}>, Model<any, any>, undefined>')

This site is currently running and I pulled the code from GitHub.  I'm trying to figure out if I am missing a package or something.

Here is my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "zenexint.com",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "bin/build/server.bundle.js",
  "description": "ZenexInt.com",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack -d -w --env.development",
    "build": "webpack -p --env.production"
  },
 
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.0",
    "@types/mongoose": "5.10.5",
    "@types/node": "^6.9.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.3",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "client-sessions": "^0.8.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "is-plain-object": "^2.0.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "kind-of": "^6.0.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.4.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.6",
    "nodemailer": "^6.2.1",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
    "npm": "^7.11.1",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^1.0.5",
    "react-magnifier": "^3.0.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the code producing the error:

```
import express from "express";

import { set_catalog, set_meta, } from "../redux/actions";
import { ZenexProduct as Product } from '../models/mongoose/models';
import { MetaProducts } from "../meta";
import { mapItems } from "./utils";
import { ZenexItem } from "../models/mongoose/schemas";

import Catalog from "../models/Catalog";

var r = express.Router();

r.use((req, res, next) => {

    let catalog = Catalog();

    if (req.query.limit) { catalog.limit = Number(req.query.limit); }
    if (req.query.skip) { catalog.skip = Number(req.query.skip); }
    if (req.query.sort) { catalog.sort = req.query.sort; }

    res.locals.store.dispatch(set_catalog(catalog));
    res.locals.store.dispatch(set_meta(MetaProducts));

    next();

});

r.use('/category/:Category/:Subcategory', async (req, res, next) => {

    const { Category, Subcategory } = req.params;
    let { catalog, meta } = res.locals.store.getState();

    let q = { $and: [{ Category: { $regex: Category, $options: "i" } }, { Subcategory: { $regex: Subcategory, $options: "i" } }] };
    catalog.count = await Product.find(q).countDocuments().exec()
    catalog.items = (await Product.find(q).sort(catalog.sorts[catalog.sort]).skip(catalog.skip).limit(catalog.limit).exec()).map(d => d._doc);
    catalog.category = Category;
    catalog.subcategory = Subcategory;
    meta.title = 'Private Label ' + Subcategory + ': Zenex International';
    meta.description = 'We manufacture and can private label ' + Subcategory + ' and other quality products for your business today.';
    res.locals.store.dispatch(set_catalog(catalog));
    res.locals.store.dispatch(set_meta(meta));

    next();

});

r.use('/category/:Category', async (req, res, next) => {

    const { Category } = req.params;
    let { catalog, meta } = res.locals.store.getState();

    //if(formalize(Category) !== Category) { res.redirect("/category/" + formalize(Category)); }

    if (catalog.items.length === 0) {
        let q = { Category: { $regex: Category, $options: "i" } };
        catalog.count = await Product.find(q).countDocuments().exec();
        catalog.items = (await Product.find(q).sort(catalog.sorts[catalog.sort]).skip(catalog.skip).limit(catalog.limit).exec()).map(d => d._doc);
        catalog.category = Category;
        meta.title = 'Private Label ' + Category + ': Zenex International';
        meta.description = 'We manufacture and can private label ' + Category + ' and other quality  products for your business today.';
        res.locals.store.dispatch(set_catalog(catalog));
        res.locals.store.dispatch(set_meta(meta));
    }

    next();

});

r.use('/family/:Family', async (req, res, next) => {

    const { Family } = req.params;
    let { catalog, meta } = res.locals.store.getState();

    if (catalog.items.length === 0) {
        var query = { Family: Family.substring(0, Family.length - 1).toLowerCase() };
        catalog.count = await Product.find(query).countDocuments().exec();
        catalog.items = (await Product.find(query).sort(catalog.sorts[catalog.sort]).skip(catalog.skip).limit(catalog.limit).exec()).map(d => d._doc);
        meta.title = 'Private Label ' + Family + ': Zenex International';
        meta.description = 'Wholesale Distribution and Private Label ' + Family + 's: Zenex International';
        catalog.items = catalog.items;
        catalog.family = Family;
        res.locals.store.dispatch(set_catalog(catalog));
        res.locals.store.dispatch(set_meta(meta));
    }

    next();

});

r.use('/nameSearch/:text', async (req, res, next) => {

    const { text } = req.params;

    let { catalog, meta } = res.locals.store.getState();

    if (catalog.items.length === 0) {

        let query = ["ProductID", "Name", "Title", "Keywords", "Subcategory", "Category", "Description"].reduce((q, field) => {
            q.$or.push({ [field]: { "$regex": text, "$options": "i" } });
            q.$or.push({ $and: text.split(' ').map(t => ({ [field]: { "$regex": t, "$options": "i" } })) });
            return q;
        }, { $or: [] });

        catalog.search = text;
        catalog.count = await Product.find(query).countDocuments().exec();

        if (catalog.count > 0) {
            catalog.items = (await Product.find(query).sort(catalog.sorts[catalog.sort]).limit(catalog.limit).skip(catalog.skip).exec()).map(d => d && d._doc);
            if (catalog.items.length === 1) { catalog.item = catalog.items[0]; }
            meta.title = "Professional Grade " + catalog.items[0].Category + " at Superior Value";
            meta.description = "We manufacturing and distribute " + catalog.items[0].Category + " and other high quality products for your business";
            res.locals.store.dispatch(set_catalog(catalog));
            res.locals.store.dispatch(set_meta(meta));
        }

    }

    next();

});

r.use('/:ProductID', async (req, res, next) => {

    const { ProductID } = req.params;
    let { catalog, meta } = res.locals.store.getState();

    if (catalog.items.length === 0) {
        catalog.count = await Product.find({ ProductID }).countDocuments().exec();
        catalog.item = (await Product.findOne({ ProductID }).exec());
        if (catalog.item) {
            catalog.item = catalog.item._doc;
            meta.title = `Private Label "${catalog.item.Name}: ${catalog.item.Title}", Zenex Intl.`;
            meta.description = `We private label "${catalog.item.Name}" ${catalog.item.Title}, and other ${catalog.item.Type}'s for your business today.`;
            catalog.category = catalog.item.Category;
            catalog.subcategory = catalog.item.Subcategory;
            catalog.family = catalog.item.Family;
            catalog.items = [catalog.item];
            res.locals.store.dispatch(set_catalog(catalog));
            res.locals.store.dispatch(set_meta(meta));
        }
    }

    next();

});

r.use("/", async (req, res, next) => {

    let { catalog } = res.locals.store.getState();

    if (catalog.items.length === 0) {
        catalog.count = await Product.find({}).countDocuments();
        catalog.items = (await Product.find({}).sort(catalog.sorts[catalog.sort]).skip(catalog.skip).limit(catalog.limit).exec()).map(d => d._doc);
    }

    catalog.items = catalog.items.map(mapItems);

    catalog.items.map(async (i, index) => {

        if (i.Hardware) {
            let hardware;
            try { hardware = await ZenexItem.findOne({ ProductID: i.Hardware }).exex(); }
            catch (error) { console.log(error); }
        }

        return i;

    });

    if (catalog.items.length === 1) {
        catalog.item = catalog.items[0];
    }

    res.locals.store.dispatch(set_catalog(catalog));

    next();

});

export default r;
```

Does it look I am missing something or is there a bigger issue that I need to find?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

The problem is that you have to extend from Model.

To be allowed to use findOne method in mongoose with typescript you have to do some steps before:

1. Create an interface
2. Create another interface that extends from Model and must be generic
3. Implement these interfaces into your Schema and model

[Here in mongoose documentation is very well explained](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/statics.html), in my case, I had

```
interface IUser2 {
  name: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

interface UserModel extends IUser2 {
  findUserByCredentials(): any;
}
```

And it has to be

```
interface IUser2 {
  name: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

                               // look here
// Extending from Model will allow you to use findOne method
interface UserModel extends Model<IUser2> {
  findUserByCredentials(): any;
}
```

Your final code should look like this

```
import { Model, Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

interface IUser {
  name: string;
}

interface UserModel extends Model<IUser> {
  myStaticMethod(): number;
}

const schema = new Schema<IUser, UserModel>({ name: String });
schema.static('myStaticMethod', function myStaticMethod() {
  return 42;
});

const User = model<IUser, UserModel>('User', schema);

const answer: number = User.myStaticMethod(); // 42
```